# Jax-RS Only the first call to the rest service from browser works

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, apache-tomee, openejb

I'm trying to develop a rest service with jax-rs and tomee server (v 1.7.3)
Everything work properly for the first request and then I have this error.

> javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.namespacePrefixMapper, value:
>   org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.NamespaceMapper

I tried to add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

But it doesn't work when I run my server (mvn tomee:run). I have now this error :

> GRAVE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war
>   StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/wishlist-jee]
>   org.apache.openejb.config.ValidationFailedException: Module failed
>   validation. AppModule(name=wishlist-jee)

Someone have already seen this error ?

My code is available on Git (https://github.com/AlexisDuf/wishlist-jee)

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem with TomEE 1.7.4.
It works for me after I copied

- jaxb-impl.jar
- jaxb-core-2.2.7.jar

from the TomEE/lib to the TomEE/endorsed folder.